# Convert JSON key value using RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I receive a JSON string from a server call, in this form:

```
{"0":{"jpgN":"2","spread_value":"392.22","relevant_new":"text"},"1":{"jpgN":"1","spread_value":"395.28","relevant_new":"text"},"count":2}
```

Using RegExp, is there any way to replace the value of any key jpgN with the string `"http://mydomain.com/keyValue.jpg"` (eg `"http://mydomain.com/2.jpg"`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that ?

```
var json = {"0":{"jpgN":"2","spread_value":"392.22","relevant_new":"text"},"1":{"jpgN":"1","spread_value":"395.28","relevant_new":"text"},"count":2};
var s = JSON.stringify(json);

s.replace(/\"jpgN\":\"(\w+)\"/g, "\"jpgN\":\"http://mydomain.com/$1.jpg\"");
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `"jpgN":"([^"]+)"` to `"jpgN":"http://mydomain.com/$1.jpg"`.

But it's better to parse json and change values using your programming language.